# Execved process not reading from stdin

Tags: stdin, exec

I have a program A doing the following:

1. Read 2 Bytes from input
2. Print read input
3. `exec`ing into program B.

Program B does the following

1. Read 2 Bytes from input
2. Print input

To make it concrete following are programs A, B:

A:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char a[3];
  fgets(a, 3, stdin);
  printf("%s\n", a);
  char* args[] = {NULL};
  execv("./read2", args);
}
```

B:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   char a[] = "hy";
   fgets(a, 3, stdin);
   printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

When I execute it like `echo 'abcd' | ./A`, I expected the following output

```
ab
cd
```

But I get
    ab
    hy

Why isn't `B` reading from its standard input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: the parent MUST use unbuffered IO if the subsequent process needs to read exactly from where the parent left off.

With not-buffered IO, the program behaves correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buf[3];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 2);
    printf("%s '%s'\n", *argv, buf);
    if (strcmp(*argv, "./childtu") == 0) return 0;
    execl("./readtwo", "./childtu", (char *) 0);
}
```

As run via

```
$ make readtwo            
cc     readtwo.c   -o readtwo
$ echo abcdefg | ./readtwo
./readtwo 'ab'
./childtu 'cd'
$
```

Buffered IO (via `fgets`) in the parent is the problem, as the child will only be able to read from standard input if there's more input than what the parent reads off in advance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buf[3];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fgets(buf, 3, stdin);
    printf("%s '%s'\n", *argv, buf);
    if (strcmp(*argv, "./childtu") == 0) return 0;
    execl("./readtwo", "./childtu", (char *) 0);
}
```

If curious one could binary search for the exact buffer size, or see what is set in the kernel:

```
$ perl -e 'print(("a")x99999)' | ./readtwo
./readtwo 'aa'
./childtu 'aa'
$
```

With `strace` (or similar) we can observe how much the parent process `read`s from standard input (fd 0):

```
$ echo asdf | strace -o blah ./readtwo
./readtwo 'as'
./childtu ''
$ fgrep 'read(0' blah
read(0, "asdf\n", 4096)                 = 5
read(0, "", 4096)                       = 0
$
```

Here, the parent wanted 4096 bytes (but only got five), and the `exec`'d process got zero as there's nothing left. So don't use a buffered read in the parent process if this is a problem.

Comment: Strange. If I replace my fgets with read, it works indeed

Comment: @nitishch not strange at all, it's to be expected with buffered I/O

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Can you elaborate the comment as an answer